# Drupal 7 is not showing search block without login

Tags: drupal

i am new to drupal, i want to add search form in sidebar, i logged-in as administrator and went to "Structure -> Blocks ->" then went into Disabled section and select the Search Form and select sidebar bar from drop down of Region, but it is showing on login, when i open it without login it is not showing, please let me know what to do to show Search Form for every one.

Thank you very much.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

You have to go to the `Administer › User management` section,under the `search module` area,you need to give the necessary permission to the user that needs to see the search form.If you want everyone to view this `Search Module` check the box corresponding to `anonymous` and `authenticated` users.That will do the trick... :)

Answer (score 1):

Hi I'm using Drupal 7 I went to Modules > Search > Permissions scroll down to search and ticked Anoynous user use search and it worked.